# "Firstly" or "first"?

Tags: adverbs, numbers, ordinal-numbers, discourse-markers, flat-adverbs

Which is more correct?

> How do I love thee? Let me count the ways. **First,** thy eyes gaze deep into my soul. **Second,**...

or

> There are four reasons why all should hail the Hypno-Toad. **Firstly,** his eyes gaze deep into your soul. **Secondly,**...

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of that; you can't really deduct from a discussion on "fast" as an adverb whether to prefer "first" or "firstly".

Comment: In fact this is a great question! I remember having wondered about this too.

Comment: The same question, with more quotations: [When enumerating motivations, is it correct to write firstly, secondly, …, or first, second, …?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/886/when-enumerating-motivations-is-it-correct-to-write-firstly-secondly-or/890#890)

Comment: Closely related, though perhaps not a duplicate: ["First, ... Secondly, ... &c.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273525/first-secondly-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think either one is OK. Some (American) people object to firstly, secondly etc.

Eric Partridge ("Usage and Abusage") says:

> **firstly** is traditionally said to be inferior to *first*, even when *secondly*, *thirdly* ... follow it.

Comment: Firstly has been arround since 1500s~, I think the concern is people worried about it being a slang word.

Answer (score 12):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* reports the following note:

> *First*, *second*, *third*, etc., are adverbs as well as adjectives: "First, dice three potatoes; second, add the bouillon." *Firstly*, *secondly*, etc., are also correct, but make sure not to mix the two groups: *first, second, third*; not *first, secondly, thirdly*.

Answer (score 9):

Both are correct, however, there is "overcorrectness" in using *firstly* because it seems more like an adverb than *first*.

Go on the length principle: both have the same meaning, but *firstly* is two characters longer than *first*. The language will eventually evolve to do without the longer equivalent; I'd use *first*.

Comment: "The language will eventually evolve to do without the longer equivalent; I'd use firstly." Isn't there a contraction here? If the language will evolve to use the shorter word, why would you the longer word?

Comment: Yeah, did you mean to conclude with "I'd use first"? That'd make more sense.

Comment: ...Well pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think one is more correct than the other. Though I prefer "First" because "Firstly" sounds a little old English.
The important part is you remain consistent. If you use firstly, you must use secondly, thirdly, etc.

EDIT: I found an exception (with regards to the consistency part)

> The older standard is first, secondly,
>   thirdly, etc.The Oxford English Dictionary gives the following quote from Johnson's Dictionary, which didn't include word firstly: ‘Some late authors use Firstly for the sake of its more accordant sound with secondly, thirdly, etc.’

Comment: "Firstly" doesn't sound Old English to my ears. Is it because I was butchering Shakespeare in the example sentence? I've switched them around. ;-)

Comment: It probably just sounds old English to be because modern authors prefer "first" to "firstly". :D

Answer (score 2):

#### Three answers come to mind

1. Strictly it should be "Firstly", because that is an adverb, and in these quotations it is modifying a clause (i.e. a verb).  some English users will feel uncomfortable with this.
2. Practically / pragmatically, it could be "First", because most English users will understand perfectly well what this means, and will not feel uncomfortable with it.
3. Poetically (as in the Shakesperean quotation) it can be anything the author likes, because rules of syntax and grammar are frequently bent or broken for poetic effect.

Personally, I would use "Firstly", for the first reason.

For the record:  I'm English, so my English may well differ from American English.

Comment: Regarding (1), usage does not suggest that we ought to use "firstly" in all cases where it would be an adverb.  In that case, it would be better to say "I'll go firstly", which it clearly is not.  The word *first* is both an adjective and an adverb to begin with, so argument one is moot.  This is mostly a pragmatics/style issue.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, good point, but I _suspect_ that in "I'll go first", "first" is not describing how you will go, but that the sentence is a contraction of something along the lines of "I will go in first position", and that "first" is a noun in that case.  I realise that many will disagree!  Still, my gut tells me that it is a stylistic thing at the end of the day.

Comment: I think you are mistakenly being too narrow in your definition of adverb.  Adverbs don't only modify verbs; they can modify entire sentences.  *Yesterday* is an adverb, for example, in the sentence, "I went there yesterday."  If you still don't believe me, then look at the adverb definitions (and particularly the example sentences) of *first* from dictionary.com: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/first

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct to use, however, when the word "firstly" comes to mind I believe it's used traditionally and to list things. When you use "first" it could mean you are denoting a proposition before anything else.

Answer (score -1):

To me *firstly* is chiefly British, while *first* chiefly American. Now, this doesn't mean *firstly* is never used in AmE, but only less common than that of *first*.

Comment: I totally agree with this as an Indian. I remember being told by an American not to use 'Firstly', whereas in India, I had never heard 'First' being used. Don't know why this comment has been downvoted.