# Can "firstly" be used in the same meaning as "at first/initially"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I've come across many sources claiming that the words ***firstly*** and ***first*** (as an adverb) can be used interchangeably. They, however, only seemed to be comparing their meanings with regard to enumerations - *first(ly) I want to say ..., second(ly) ..., last(ly) ...*

What bothers me more is if the word ***firstly*** is also usable within the meaning of ***at first*** or ***initially*** like in the sentence:

> Muons *(subatomic particles)* were *firstly* observed in cosmic rays.

The word ***first*** fits there very well, but is that the case for ***firstly*** too? I have not found a dictionary definition or example saying so.

Comment: If you label the pragmatic (material-organising) marker usage of _first / firstly_ as such, it simplifies matters. Then you can check the adverbial usages of _first_, say at [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/first).  Though admittedly they still have the dustbin adverb class. Which usage/s of _first_ does it say overlap with that/those of _firstly_?

Comment: Related issues are covered by [“Firstly” or “first”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/) (and [When enumerating motivations, is it correct to write firstly, secondly, …, or first, second, …?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/886/) over on ELL), from which my impression is pedants and/or Americans don't like ***firstly*** so much even in contexts where I see little difference. But in OP's "strictly chronological" context here I think probably *no-one* would endorse it.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. I was really only lacking evidence that ***firstly*** is not used correctly in the cited sentence, since many sources rendered *first* and *firstly* equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly (see what I did there?): No.   ***Firstly*** can't be used in the same meaning as ***at first*** or ***initially***.  As @deadrat mentioned, *"firstly" meaning first is restricted to enumerations, so the initial observation of muons would be the first time*.

Secondly, depending on the context of the text, the use of firstly in the excerpt you've given us may be correct after all (though with an incorrect word order). **But I only consider this option because I read a lot of scientific papers and I know that grammar and writing isn't their (scientists) strong suit**.  I assume it should indeed be ***first***, but I'll expand on my reasoning:

If the text is about how muons were originally observed for the first time ever, then yes, it should be ***first***.

However, if the context of the text is different (i.e. it talks about how muons were observed in an experiment), then ***firstly*** could be correct.  But only if it's followed by additional ways muons were observed.  As I mentioned before, I **only** consider this because I know the grammar in a lot of scientific papers is horrendous.  The only context I would accept firstly in would be:

> "muons were observed firstly in cosmic rays, secondly in radioactive decay, [...]"

And that is assuming that the author of the text isn't great at grammar (which on a whole, they are not).  The excerpt you've given is too short to be sure what the author meant.

So in short: ***firstly*** is only for enumerations and **if** the context of the paper meant it in that way, then the phrase you have shown us is gramatically incorrect (word order), but experience has taught me that in scientific papers, both of these options (incorrect use of *firstly* or just an incorrect word order) are possible.

*PS: Thank you @FumbleFingers for pointing out I wasn't very clear in my reasoning behind my consideration of the second (though gramatically incorrect) option.*

Comment: I don't recognise this distinction at all. *To cook roast rabbit, **firstly** catch your rabbit, then pop it in the oven?* I don't think so.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't understand the analogy you're making here. Is it possible you misread the original post or the context I allow ***firstly*** to be used in here?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, I see what you mean.  I included the part about ***firstly*** to show in which context of the text this would be allowed.  But I absolutely agree it cannot mean the same as *initially* or *at first* .  Thank you for pointing out it may be confusing, I'll correct that.

Comment: I'm saying the same thing as @deadrat citing OED below - *"firstly" meaning "first" is restricted to enumerations*. I cannot see any way you can meaningfully justify ***firstly*** as being an acceptable way to distinguish one way of observing muons from another (we observed muons *secondly* using the LHC?). And I'm BrE, which I suspect makes me more tolerant in this area than most AmE speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I should have added my reasoning for even considering the second option.  There's no question that phrase is gramatically incorrect.  But the way in which it is incorrect may differ.  Faulty use of *firstly* or just the word order.  I do not know the rest of the text, so I included both options just to be sure.  Reading a lot of scientific papers has taught me that it may very well just be an incorrect word order, which is why I wanted to include that possibility.  I hope my edit has clarified that.

Comment: @Glenn: From my point of view, I think you are absolutely right about wrong word orders in many scientific papers and not only that. Thank you for making it clear in your answer.

Comment: oic. Yes, I think all is clear on both sides now, and I've cancelled my downvote accordingly. If you've no objection, I'm happy to leave this "comment trail" - not least because it's referenced in the answer text now. But feel free to delete both that and your half of these "now-resolved" comments if you want. Just ping me with one final comment and I'll delete mine too. It's your "patch" so it's your call (unless the mods unilaterally sweep us both away! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Happy to leave the comments up, no problem at all.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Per the *OED*, "firstly" meaning first is restricted to enumerations, so the initial observation of muons would be the first time.